# Power Automate online excel - Can header of a column have a "/"?

Tags: power-automate

I am trying to create a flow that copies the online excel date column to a sharepoint list.
I notice date columns with a "/" do not work , but date columns without a "/" work nicely.

Is there an exception? is there a way around it?

there is no data in the compose for a field with "/"
[image]

Comment: It allows creating columns with names having `/` in it. However, SharePoint internal name will convert `/` to `_x002f_`. For example if you are creating a column with name `Date/Time`, internal name will be `Date_x002f_Time`. Are you having issue while adding value to the column name with `/` in it? did you tried using internal name of column if you are using any expression? Can you add screenshot of flow in "Edit" mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes somehow forward slashes in column headers do not work as it replaces "/" with something like ~1 for some sort of reason.

The solution is to use an expression.

Assuming your column name is "Date/Time", it will look like below:

```
items('Apply_to_each_2')?[concat('Date', '/', 'Time')]
```

Replace "Date" and "Time" with your own values.

Hope it helps!